# Why does xalan not throw a TransformException error with malformed XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

In my unit tests I am trying to throw a TransformException error by sending some malformed xml to the org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl implementation of javax.xml.transform.Transformer

calling

```
transform(Source xmlSource,Result outputTarget) throws TransformerException
```

The console shows the following message, but no TransformerException is thrown

```
file:/filepath/MalformedInput.xml; Line #85; Column #16; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

Any ideas as to why it doesn't throw a TransformerException or how I can raise an Exception for this situation?

I have tried with saxon and a TransformerException is thrown, but i would prefer to use xalan

thanks

Comment: Just curious; why would you prefer to use xalan over saxon?

Comment: A different part of the code uses a shared java library, built internally for use on our companies platform. That code doesn't work with saxon, only xalan. So I would prefer to use xalan everywhere rather than xalan & saxon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify an ErrorListener on your transformer (i believe you set this in the TransformerFactory).

Comment: thanks. I have tried version v2.6.0 of xalan and the TransformerException error is thrown without specifying an ErrorListener when the xml doc is malformed. Looks like this was removed in v2.7.1 & a specific ErrorListener needs to be set